# Localized resx resources are not being loaded from App_GlobalResources folder when changing culture on the fly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I have a solution consisting of two MVC3 projects with resources located in each project's **App_GlobalResources** folder:

**MyApp.Web project**'s App_GlobalResources folder contains default resources (default culture is en-US) such as **MyPage1.resx**

**MyApp.Web.Europe project** - App_GlobalResources folder contains resources for European cultures such as **MyPage1.de-DE.resx**. It's a startup project.

When I change culture on the fly setting **Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture** and  **Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture** what I have is that resources from MyApp.Web.Europe App_GlobalResources folder are not being loaded.

In addition to that MyApp.Web core project also contains some resources in Resources folder for all cultures, so when I change culture on the fly, European resources such as de-DE are being loaded from Resources folder fine.
Does someone have any considerations how to make them load from App_GlobalResources?